# Selected Listbox value must equal a range

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I created a useform in Excel VBA with a listbox cotaining two values. Only one value can be selected at a time. I am using the click event on the listbox and when a user clicks a value in the listbox then a specific range (cell) value becomes that value the user clicked in the listbox. The event code looks as follows,

```
Private Sub lbPeriod_Click() 
    Range("input_Period").Value = frmInput.lbPeriod.Text 
End Sub
```

The user can also close the userform and open the userform with a button in the excel sheet with the following 2 subroutines,

```
Sub showInputWizard()
    If frmInput.Visible = False Then
        Load frmInput
        frmInput.Show
    Else
        Unload frmInput
    End If
End Sub
```

The reason for the unload is because another listbox in the userform must take on different values given the active sheet. When the userform gets activated one of the values in the listbox (lbPeriod) must be selected based on the value of a range (`Range("input_Period").Value`). On the form initialize event i use the following code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Top = Application.Top + 270
    Me.Left = Application.Left + 750
    Me.lbPeriod = Range("input_period").Value
End Sub
```

What i have noticed is that when i open the form and click a value my range value change (which is correct) but when i close and open the form again the range value (`Range("input_period").Value`) becomes blank. I tested it with a Double click event and the double click event does not give this problem. I also have to mention the range is also a dropdown list of the two values. What can i do?

I also see that the double click event has a `ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean` extenstion. Is it possible to use such an extension with one click?

I can possibly create two forms that look simillar two each other, but i would not prefer that.

Comment: I can't see where you fill your listbox up in your code. Is the _"button in excel sheet"_ the only way a user has to load the userform? or is it called modelessly by a macro and the user can click the _"button in excel sheet"_ while it's already shown?